# How to create a loop from a string based on a delimiter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this:

```
var string = ' [United States] [Canada] [India] ';
```

I want to do a for loop and add each of the countries into an array in Javascript or Jquery, something like this:

```
var countryArray = new Array();
for ( each country in string AS country) {
  countryArray.push(country);      
}
```

I'm not sure how I would make a foreach loop out of a string like that.

Comment: You can get that array with a regular expression...

Comment: Did you try splitting the string with `"[U] [C] [I]".split(' ');` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
var arr = str.match(/\[.+?\]/g).map(function (s) { return s.slice(1, -1); });
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/bWC9F/

There's probably a better way to do it, though...

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this

```
string.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g).map(function(inp){return inp.substring(1, inp.length - 1)})
```

wow. exact same thing

Comment: Yea, pretty much `:)` I think it's possible to make the `match` method return the strings without the brackets, but I don't know how to do that....

Answer (score 2):

split()?

```
var string = ' [United States] [Canada] [India] ';
var arr = string.split(/([[^[]*])/ );

alert(arr);
```

Comment: This won't work, as this will display the output like this - [United States,], [Canada,], [India,],. Please check here- http://jsfiddle.net/4yHp5/